# Поместить изображение в определенную форму

Tags: html, css, photoshop

Хочу придать изображениям определенную форму. Не знаю, есть ли возможность сделать это чисто через css, при этом не прибегая к изображению, которое будет задавать такую форму. Скриншоты прилагаются.

Пытался сделать с помощью `border-image`, но это видимо не то..

[image: что должно получится]

[image: изображение чтоб задать форму]

[image: собственно сама фотография]

```css
.picture-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  border-image: url('../img/forimg.png') 24 24 24 24 stretch stretch;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: inset;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="picture-container">
    <img src="img/3.png" alt="scope1">
  </div>
  <p class="description">Автоматизированная система температуорных датчиков обеспечивает техническую возможность использования ТГ для качественной сушки древесины в мягком, нормальном и форсированном режимах.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: Самый простой способ - действительно использовать картинку такой формы. Если на чистом css - это куча псевдоэлементов :befort и :after которые будут накладываться на картинку с помощью position: absolute, а потом ещё и адаптивность всей этой прелести реализовывать. Словом, проще взять картинку нужной формы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.picture-container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  border-radius: 50%/ 20%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  border-radius: 20%/ 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="picture-container">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfaJ5.png" alt="scope1">
  </div>
  <p class="description">Автоматизированная система температуорных датчиков обеспечивает техническую возможность использования ТГ для качественной сушки древесины в мягком, нормальном и форсированном режимах.</p>
</article>
```